# Tostring() has been removed. Please call tobytes() instead

Tags: 12.04, python, python-2.7, css

I try to install Reddit on my ubuntu server but I get an error after "make" line.

Please see the all lines from the server.

```
[+] including definitions from Makefile.py
python setup.py build
Cannot find Baseplate. Skipping Thrift build.
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
python setup.py build_ext --inplace  # copy the .so files from cython into the source tree
Cannot find Baseplate. Skipping Thrift build.
running build_ext
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/r2/lib/sgm.so -> r2/lib
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/r2/lib/wrapped.so -> r2/lib
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/r2/lib/db/_sorts.so -> r2/lib/db
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/r2/lib/mr_tools/_mr_tools.so -> r2/lib/mr_tools
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/r2/lib/utils/_utils.so -> r2/lib/utils
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/r2/lib/utils/comment_tree_utils.so -> r2/lib/utils
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Cfilters.so -> 
# see above
rm -f build/public/static/sprite-reddit.png build/public/static/reddit.css
python r2/lib/nymph.py build/public/static/css/reddit.less build/public/static/sprite-reddit.png > build/public/static/css/reddit.less.tmp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "r2/lib/nymph.py", line 185, in <module>
    print spritify(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
  File "r2/lib/nymph.py", line 178, in spritify
    images = _load_spritable_images(css_filename)
  File "r2/lib/nymph.py", line 94, in _load_spritable_images
    image_hash = hashlib.md5(image.convert("RGBA").tostring()).hexdigest()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Pillow-3.2.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/PIL/Image.py", line 699, in tostring
    "Please call tobytes() instead.")
Exception: tostring() has been removed. Please call tobytes() instead.
make: *** [build/public/static/reddit.css] Error 1
```

It is not a bug of the script because I found some similar posting but is not applicable for me too.
https://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/19ntpk/make_fails_buildpublicstaticredditcss_error_127/ and
https://www.reddit.com/comments/26dasw/_/

Something are missing or is set wrong but I don't know what...
Please help me to fix it.

Comment: As stated in https://askubuntu.com/a/768450/576209 you need to downgrade Pillow. As of 16-07-2018 you should use Pillow 2.8.1, as 2.1.0 will throw an error and will not be succesfully installed.

Answer (score 3):

The code needs an older version (before 3.0) of Pillow than the one you have (3.2.0).

Try to remove your manually installed Pillow from `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Pillow-3.2.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg` and install an older version instead.

Comment: Great. I try to install as per: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.1.0 but the terminal install 3.2 not 2.1. Some help how to unistall 3.2.0 again and install an older version ?

Comment: If you've used `pip` install your current Pillow then `pip install Pillow==2.1.0` should get you v2.1.0